# Who established the Wagga Country Fire Brigade?

Tags: 19th-century, australia, new-south-wales, historical-context

I am seeking information on the Country Fire Brigade in New South Wales and in particular the establishment of the Wagga Wagga unit. This relates to my search for information on Thomas (Tot) Linsell (Lindsell) born 1847, and the family story he was one of the founders. I have had no success with the NSW Government, an unanswered query to Wagga Historical Society and only one reference in [Trove](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/13682888) at NLA. I have googled extensively on Country Fire Brigade and not found anything relevant except the reference to Trove.

I am wanting information on the involvement of Thomas Linsell to see if the Brigade had a financial effect on him or family and what amount of time/involvement the family had.

Comment: In our beta mode, I think Henry's question is an example of why we should encourage members to provide some details and references about the underlying work. The remarks don't need to be fancy, but if Henry is so inclined, adding a little detail and references to the name "Tot Lindsell" and to the "Wagga Wagga" unit in that family story would provide a little context to the question. Adding the reference found in Trove at NLA would likewise be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I googled for `Wagga fire brigade "history"` and found this [WaggaWagga local history page](http://waggalocalhistory.wetpaint.com/page/Bushfires+of+1904-5) which mentions the Wagga Wagga advertiser as a potential source, in 1904-1906.

However, this doesn't gel with the entries on trove (search for `wagga brigade`) -- there are a significant number for the decade 1890-1900, especially as rooting around on the Wagga Wagga local history page, under the "walking  tour of Wagga Wagga's historic buildings", I find:

> The first fire brigade was established in 1880 in a two roomed wooden cottage in Baylis Street. In 1883 it moved to Morrow Street near the present Civic Theatre but that burnt down so they moved to what is now Sunflower House and then, in 1926, moved here [*the Esplanade*].

Comment: @Henry, my Google search for "Country fire brigade" "wagga" throws up the link to a newpaper report in January 1887 http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1302&dat=18870108&id=n1oQAAAAIBAJ&sjid=V5MDAAAAIBAJ&pg=6866,480980 as well as a Trove link for a newspaper report in April 1888 which is the reference I suspect you have found. Do you know what timeframe is relevant to Thomas Linsell's involvement?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia says..."History

The New South Wales Fire Brigades (NSWFB) was established in September 1909, replacing the Sydney based Metropolitan Fire Brigade, which formed in February 1884.[3] Prior to its formation, Fire Brigade Boards also ran rudimentary fire services in various New South Wales country towns. On 1 January 2011 the agency was renamed to Fire and Rescue NSW to better reflect the agency's expanding responsibilities.[4]"

Comment: Country Fire Brigade was before the establishment of these entities.